# Change text in SVG image with JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Currently, I am working with SVG image and JS. I want to change the text content in the SVG image. Actually, I already did it, but sometimes it's work, sometimes not. I use the function below:

```
function injectSVG(params) {

  var svgChart = document.getElementById("item-svg-chart").contentDocument;
  var text = svgChart.querySelectorAll('text.text-inject');
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    text[i].textContent = params[i].toString().replace("*", "\xB0");
  }
}
```

with `params` content new text will be injected.

The code I used to show svg on html:

```
<div class="img-fluid">
  <object alt="svg-chart" id="item-svg-chart" data="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/rf-weldneck-flange.svg') }}"></object>
</div>
```

SVG images will change with the code below (I also query it):

```
  $('#third-select-card').on("change", function(e){
    var link = selectChange();
    $("#item-svg-chart").attr('data', link);
    var svgChart = document.getElementById("item-svg-chart");
    console.log(svgChart);
    var svgChart_1 = document.getElementById("item-svg-chart").contentDocument;
    console.log(svgChart_1);
  })
```

with `svgChart` show svg A (for example), `svgChart_1` show `contentDocument` of svg A and `link` is the link to SVG image. But when query the `svgChart` and `svgChart_1` I saw they were not the same svg `contenDocument` but it show the same image on my web (see attached images):

[image: Query svgChart]

[image: Query svgChart_1]

I don't know why it show the same image on web, but `contentDocument` is different. I think it's maybe the reason why I can not inject new text to svg.

Can someone help me explain why `contentDocument` is different ? And if the code I posted above is meaningless, please tell me there are anyway to change text content in svg image ?. This issue got me 2 days for it.

Thanks for help!